# Handle Arrow keys in a UserControl to select List Item while the TextBox in UserControl has focus

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, list, user-controls

I have a designed a UserControl for List, which further having a **UserControl** which is **ListItem**, So far I have gained access by clicking the **ListItem** on **ClickEvent** and Up-till Form where I used That **ListControl**,

The Issue is, I am showing That List Control On a **SearchTextBox** , I want to do is , When I press Down-Arrow key from Keyboard, I focus to the ListControl, Now I want to control the Up-Down arrow key to select an Item from List,

All the **ListItems** are add over a Panel Control in **UserControl**.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `ProcessCmdKey` and do what you want.

Assuming you have for example a `ListBox` in that `UserControl`:

**VB Code**

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Down Then
        'Perform validations and so on then
        Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Down)
    {
        //Perform validations and so on then
        this.listBox1.SelectedIndex= this.listBox1.SelectedIndex+1;
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Te Above Control is Self Created Control Which having Panel and Number Of Rows(listitemcontrol), So I have to write down ProcessCmdKey onto that ListUserControl?

Comment: @DareDevil If you have a control that host that `Panel` and `TextBox` and ...put the logic in your `UserControl`

Comment: @DareDevil  you can test it independent from other stuff in project, as a simple test, you can crate a `UserControl`, and put a `TextBox` and a `ListBox` on it and then use codes.